Characterizing the family of maximal cliques of a cograph
Preamble #1
There are two common equivalent definitions of cographs:

the smallest class that includes $K_1$ and is closed under disjoint union and complementation (or join);
the finite $P_4$-free graphs (i.e. no induced $P_4$ subgraphs).

An alternative, less common definition is:

the finite graphs whose every induced subgraph has the CK property.

Where a graph has the CK property iff every maximal clique intersects every maximal kernel (a.k.a. stable set, independent set, or anti-clique) at exactly one vertex.
Preamble #2
Given a family of sets $\mathcal{X}$ define
$$
\mathcal{X}^\perp = \left\{ X \subseteq \bigcup\mathcal{X} \;\middle|\; \forall Y \in \mathcal{X}. |X \cap Y| = 1 \right\}
$$
i.e. $\mathcal{X}^\perp$ is the family of all subsets of $\bigcup\mathcal{X}$ that intersect every set in $\mathcal{X}$ at exactly one point.
Let $\mathcal{C}(G)$ denote the family of all maximal cliques of the graph $G$:
Proposition. If $G$ is a cograph, then $\mathcal{C}(G) = \mathcal{C}(G)^{{\perp}{\perp}}$.
The question
Is there any known proof or counterexample for the following conjecture?
Conjecture 1. If $\mathcal{C}(H) = \mathcal{C}(H)^{{\perp}{\perp}}$ for all induced subgraphs $H$ of a finite graph $G$, then $G$ is a cograph.
My attempts
I attempted a proof, but I got stuck.
I would like to show that

For any finite $G$ such that $\mathcal{C}(G) = \mathcal{C}(G)^{{\perp}{\perp}}$, $\mathcal{C}(G)^\perp$ is the set of all maximal kernels of $G$.

The reverse inclusion here is just the CK property on $G$, and then the conjecture follows from the alternative definition of cograph.
Incomplete proof. The forward inclusion is easy. For the reverse one, observe that any maximal kernel $k \in \mathcal{K}(G)$ intersects each maximal clique at one vertex at most. Now I must use the fact that $\mathcal{C}(G) = \mathcal{C}(G)^{{\perp}{\perp}}$, but I can't see how. For example I would like to argue that $k$ can always be completed to form a member of $\mathcal{C}(G)^\perp$: then, because of the forward inclusion, that completion must be $k$ itself!
I have tried and failed to construct counterexamples. I can construct a lot of graphs with some maximal kernel that's not in $\mathcal{C}(G)^\perp$, but they do not satisfy the hypothesis either. I might be missing something obvious though.
The point where I got stuck seems to be crucial in many ways.
For example, I am also wondering whether
Conjecture 2. If $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{X}^{{\perp}{\perp}}$ then $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{C}(G_{\mathcal{X}})$.
Where $G_{\mathcal{X}}$ is the graph whose vertices are all elements of members of $\mathcal{X}$ (i.e. $V_{G_{\mathcal{X}}} = \bigcup\mathcal{X}$) and such that there is an edge on $u,v$ iff they appear together in some member of $\mathcal{X}$.
Similarly, one finds that the crucial step in the proof (where I got stuck again) involves being able to complete a set $X$ that intersects some members of $\mathcal{X}^\perp$ at exactly one point to one that intersects all members of $\mathcal{X}^\perp$ at exactly one point.
In other words, both conjectures would follow from
Conjecture 3. If $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{X}^{{\perp}{\perp}}$ and $X \subseteq \bigcup\mathcal{X}$ intersects all members of $\mathcal{X}$ at one point at most, then there is $Y \in \mathcal{X}^\perp$ such that $X \subseteq Y$.
If necessary, it is ok to restrict conjectures 2,3 to the finite case (i.e. with $\bigcup\mathcal{X}$ finite).

Here is a proof of Conjecture 1.
Proof.  We prove the contrapositive.  Suppose that $G$ is not a cograph.  Then $G$ has an induced subgraph $H$ such that $H \simeq P_4$.    Let $V(H)=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $E(H)=\{12,23,34\}$.  Thus, $\mathcal{C}(H)=E(H)$ and  so $\mathcal{C}(H)^{\perp}=\{13,24\}$.  It follows that $\mathcal{C}(H)^{{\perp}{\perp}}=\{12,23,34,14\} \neq \mathcal{C}(H)$.

Thanks! So obvious in hindsight  But now I realize that I kinda botched the question, because I was seeking to prove both conj. 1 and 2, and I was hoping that making progress on 1 would unlock 2 too.
The final target would be a characterization of all the families of sets that are the family of maximal cliques of some cograph, in terms of the $(\cdot)^{\perp}$ operator.
That fits the original title of the question, but on the other hand your answer to the actual question I asked is perfectly valid, so not sure what the etiquette would be here... open a new question, or edit this one?
